# Как правильно спроектировать vue.js-компонент и подключать его в разных проектах из github-репозитория?

Tags: vue.js, github, webpack, node-modules

У меня задача разработать табличный vue.js-компонент, который можно было бы использовать в различных проектах.

**Задание сформулировано так:** Таблица должна быть реализована в отдельном репозитории на GitHub, который потом можно будет импортировать в проект как компонент из другого репозитория.

Так же мне выслали [ссылку](https://yandex.ru/search/?text=npm%20install%20module%20from%20github&clid=2270455&banerid=6302000000%3A5e817eb6443d8a004528940c&win=431&lr=131363) на поисковый запрос: "npm install module from github", который должен был помочь разобраться.

**Я полагаю, необходимо:**

- создать сборку компонента, используя webpack,
- настроить установку зависимостей для табличного компонента, используя webpack externals
- опубликовать на github
- в проекте, в котором необходимо использовать, добавьте github-репозиторий в зависимости package.json

**Вопрос** в том как правильно создать/спроектировать компонент? Что бы была возможность передавать в этот табличный компонент параметры, содержащие данные и методы.

Пример использования компонента: `<Table tableStructure="tableStructure" :tableOptions="tableOptions" />`

Буду благодарен любой подсказке или ссылке, которая поможет понять в какую сторону искать)

Comment: установите любую библиотеку компонентов, откройте ее папку, найдите файл `index.js`, и посмотрите, к чему Вам необходимо стремиться

Answer (score 0):

Начните с официальной [доки](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/packaging-sfc-for-npm.html). Также смотрите пакет vue-sfc-rollup.

Основное что сделал я, для оформления компонента в виде пакета:

1. Создал package.json с обязательным указанием наименования, описания, автора, версии, а также:

   - входные точки для разных способов подключения:

```
  "main": "dist/my-component.umd.js",
  "module": "dist/my-component.esm.js",
  "unpkg": "dist/my-component.min.js",
```

- ссылка на репозиторий на гитхабе
- тип лицензии
- ключевые слова
- перечисления файлов (можно с указанием масок), которые попадут на npm после публикации пакета
- команда запуска сборки

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup --config rollup.config.js",
   ...
```

2. Создал настроечный файл для сборки с помощью rollup (как в руководстве)

```
import pkg from './package.json'
// import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs' // Convert CommonJS modules to ES6
import vue from 'rollup-plugin-vue' // Handle .vue SFC files
import buble from '@rollup/plugin-buble' // Transpile/polyfill with reasonable browser support
import alias from '@rollup/plugin-alias'
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve'
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace'
import { uglify } from 'rollup-plugin-uglify'

const path = require('path')

const version = pkg.version
const banner = `
/*!
 * My Component v${version}
 * (c) ${new Date().getFullYear()} Author
 * Released under the MIT License.
 */
`
console.log('__dirname', __dirname)

const plugins = [
  replace({
    'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
  }),
  alias({
    resolve: ['.vue', '.js'],
    entries: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
    }
  }),
  resolve(),
  // commonjs(),
  // css(),
  vue({
    css: true // Dynamically inject css as a <style> tag
  }),
  buble({ transforms: { dangerousForOf: true } }) // Transpile to ES5
]

export default [
  // ESM build to be used with webpack/rollup.
  {
    input: 'src/index.js', // Path relative to package.json
    output: {
      format: 'esm',
      file: pkg.module,
      exports: 'named',
      banner
    },
    plugins: plugins
  }, {
    input: 'src/wrapper.js', // Path relative to package.json
    output: {
      format: 'iife',
      name: 'MyComponent',
      file: pkg.unpkg,
      exports: 'named',
      banner
    },
    plugins: [...plugins, uglify()]
  }, {
    input: 'src/wrapper.js', // Path relative to package.json
    output: {
      format: 'umd',
      file: pkg.main,
      name: 'MyComponent',
      exports: 'named',
      banner
    },
    plugins: [...plugins, uglify()]
  }
]
```

3. Создал модули src/index.js и src/wrapper.js как входную точку для подключения компонента:

index.js

```
import MyComponent from './components/MyComponent.vue'

export { MyComponent }
```

wrapper.js

```
// Import vue component
import component from './components/MyComponent.vue'

// Declare install function executed by Vue.use()
export function install (Vue) {
  if (install.installed) return
  install.installed = true
  Vue.component('MyComponent', component)
}

// Create module definition for Vue.use()
const plugin = {
  install
}

// Auto-install when vue is found (eg. in browser via <script> tag)
let GlobalVue = null
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  GlobalVue = window.Vue
} else if (typeof global !== 'undefined') {
  GlobalVue = global.Vue
}
if (GlobalVue) {
  GlobalVue.use(plugin)
}

// To allow use as module (npm/webpack/etc.) export component
export default component
```

Comment: @t0lik, 1) Я правильно понимаю, что принцип публикации vue-компонента на github не будет отличаться от публикации в npm?
2) Подготовку компонентов для публикации Вы делаете с помощью сборки Rollup: 
`"scripts": {
  "build": "rollup --config rollup.config.js",`
В актуальной документации по vue.js предлагается другой вариант [ссылка](https://cli.vuejs.org/ru/guide/build-targets.html).
Если я правильно понимаю, в package.json должна быть сборка в качестве библиотеки:
`"scripts": {
  "build": "vue-cli-service build --target lib --inline-vue",`
Какой вариант сборки Вы бы порекомендовали?

Comment: По идее содержимое должно быть одинаковое. Самое главное это наличие правильно сформированного package.json. Да, сейчас в доке немного по-другому. Можете попробовать этот вариант сборки.